# Open command prompt to access folders of a USB connected windows phone

Tags: powershell, windows-phone-8

I am trying to open a command prompt to access folders of a USB connected windows phone. I have tried several commands like the following but to no avail.

```
wmic logicaldisk get name

GET-WMIOBJECT win32_diskdrive | Where { $_.InterfaceType -eq 'USB' }
```

Could someone suggest me the best way to accomplish this without using any tool?
My task is to access the mobile device to adjust language settings using PowerShell commands.

Phone : Lumia 1020 running Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of USB drives attached to the PC, execute this command.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'"
```

If your mobile is attached as a USB disk, it should show up. From the data you get back, you should be able to extract things like Caption, Label, Name and DriveLetter. Then you can automate things a little bit further:

```
cd (Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'" | Where-Object label -eq "YourDiskName").DriveLetter
```

EDIT: Since **Get-WmiObject** command is now depreciated, the preferred way is now to use **Get-CimInstance**.

```
 Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=2"
```

Comment: Hi Jan, Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'" is not tracing  usb connected windows phone in powershell.

Comment: Hi Jan, able to connect with USB devices for the above mentioned command but not able to with Phone devices connected via USB cable.

Comment: Perhaps a different DriveType?  I don't have a Windows phone, but my Android appears to mount as a DriveType = 3

Comment: ....or perhaps it is showing something else (the only 3 drives displayed in the UI are C: D:, and my phone, but the 3rd drive remains in my Get-WmiObject list even when I unplug my phone, and the Caption is unclear: \\?\Volume{0b454197-46b5-40c4-8683-c9e1265afa55}\)

Comment: the command Get-WmiObject is deprecated, unfortunately the solution is not valid anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the phone's top-level directory using this function, then add the root folder name from explorer e.g. 'Internal Shared Storage', 'Card', etc.

```
function Get-PhoneMainDir($phoneName) {
  $o = New-Object -com Shell.Application
  $rootComputerDirectory = $o.NameSpace(0x11)
  $phoneDirectory = $rootComputerDirectory.Items() | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -eq $phoneName } | select -First 1

  if ($phoneDirectory -eq $null) {
    throw "Not found '$phoneName' folder in This computer. Connect your phone."
  }

  return $phoneDirectory;
 }
```

$phoneName is the name of the phone in Explorer, e.g. 'Pixel 5a'

A full example is available here:

https://github.com/nosalan/powershell-mtp-file-transfer/blob/master/phone_backup_recursive.ps1